# Authorization in Azure vs owin and web.config

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure, authorization, owin

I have a c# app that is hosted on Azure. I have configured the app to use external authentication via a user's Microsoft account, which works ok. However, when I add the authorization node in the web.config file, which defines 'deny users="?"', it makes no difference - a user can seemingly browse the site whether they are logged in or not. They can log in with their MS account if they choose, and that works fine.

So looking into this, I discovered the authorization feature in Azure, which allows me to use Azure Active Directory and enforce authentication for the site via the Azure management portal, which also works fine. But now I don't have access to my role definitions.

So as I am now a little confused, my first question is, does anyone know why the authorization element in the web.config had no effect?

And secondly, am I right in thinking that the external auth provider in the application is totally separate and independent of the Azure authentication provider, and so is there an advantage to using one system over the other? OWIN can use roles, that's an advamtage - is there an advantage to using Azure auth - apart from ease of switching on/off?

Relevant config sections

```
<configuration> 
 <system.web> 
   <authentication mode="Forms"> 
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="60" defaultUrl="~/" protection="All"/> 
   </authentication> 
   <authorization> 
    <allow users="*"/> 
    <deny users="?"/> 
   </authorization> 
 </system.web> 
 <system.webServer> 
  <modules> 
   <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" /> 
  </modules> 
 </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Paste your exact web.config sections - both authorization and authentication, along with any modules defitions in your system.webserver.

Comment: Here's the web.config sections:<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="60" defaultUrl="~/" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: You have interesting configuration. First it is setup to Forms, then you remove the FormsAuthenticationModule from the server. Well, when you remove the FormsAuthenticationModule and Authentication is set to Forms, it is no wonder that everyone can access the site without being prompted to enter user / password.

Comment: HI, that part was added automatically at some point, probably on creation of the project in VS. I did try removing the 'remove name="FormsAuthenticationmodule" element from the web.config but it didn't seem to make any difference. I'll try it again.

Comment: I removed the 'remove name="FormsAuthenticationmodule" element from the web.config again and tried again, but it still doesn't force login when I visit the site

Comment: If i am using Microsoft oAuth then are those settings correct, or should they be something else?

Comment: I have tried changing the web.config to <allow roles="Administrators"/><deny users="*"/>, and this works in that it forces login, but then the authentication to microsoft fails. Instead of redirecting to the default url, it stays on the login page, with a query string of: ?ReturnUrl=%2fsignin-microsoft%3fcode%3dc96b921etc...The only way I have got this to work properly is to say if (!Request.isAuthenticated) {Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");}

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing modes of Authorization.  Since you are using OWIN and c#, I'll assume your app is an MVC app.  You should read through the detailed articles and samples at [Getting Started with Asp.Net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started).  The samples are easy to walk through and to deploy to Azure for testing different Authentication/Authorization methods.

Comment: It's web forms actually, still trying to figure out how to enforce authentication as the authorize attribute isn't working